# Invoke a matlab method in C# code with parameters

Tags: c#, matlab, reflection, invoke, method-parameters

I am trying to invoke a matlab method in my C# code with parameters. I used reflection to load a dll with the matlab funcion at runtime into my application, which works fine:

```
Assembly matlabAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(info.FullName);

List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

types = matlabAssembly.GetTypes().ToList();

List<MethodInfo> methods = new List<MethodInfo>();
methods.AddRange(types[0].GetMethods());

dynamic dynamicObject = Activator.CreateInstance(types[0]);
```

The dll contains one type with one function:

```
MWArray MyMatlabFunction(MWArray, MWArray, MWArray, MWArray);
```

I create a few arrays and want to pass them as parameters to this function. To make the type `MWArray` available to C# at compile time, i added the Assembly "MWArray.dll" from the Matlab runtime statically to my project.

```
MWArray array1 = new MWNumericArray(120);
MWArray array2 = new MWNumericArray(100);
MWArray array3 = new MWNumericArray(15);
MWArray array4 = new MWLogicalArray(true);
object[] params = new object[] {array1, array2, array3, array4};

MethodInfo matlabFuncion = methods[5]; //MyMatlabFunction

matlabFunction.Invoke(dynamicObject, params);
```

When i call the invoke method, I get an exception that an `MWNummericArray` cannot be converted into an `MWArray` although `MWNummericArray` directly derives from `MWArray`. Am I missing something or am I doing it completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon the same problem here is the solution I found:

When you want to run Matlab code in your C# application, you need a reference to the "MWArray.dll" from the Matlab runtime. If you add the reference to this dll statically to your project however, it won´t work because the reference can somehow not be loaded.

The solution is to load load the reference to "MWArray" also with reflection and create instances to "MWArray" dynamically.

```
public void Foo()
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);

    // Load dll which was exported from Matlab into application
    string path = @"..\..\..\..\MatlabDlls\Matlab-Integration";
    string dllName = "MyExportedMatlabDLL.dll";
    List<string> dllPaths = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(file => file.EndsWith(dllName)).ToList();

    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(dllPaths[0]);
    Assembly matlabAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(info.FullName);

    // Get types from exported dll
    List<Type> exportedMatlabTypes = new List<Type>();
    exportedMatlabTypes = matlabAssembly.GetTypes().ToList();

    List<MethodInfo> methods = new List<MethodInfo>();
    methods.AddRange(exportedMatlabTypes[0].GetMethods());

    // Create instance of exported Matlabtype 
    dynamic dynamicObject = Activator.CreateInstance(exportedMatlabTypes[0]);

    // Select MWArray from loaded Assemblies
    // Important: MWArray could only be loaded into the application with
    // the ResolveEventHandler further below
    Assembly mwArrayAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(name => name.FullName.Contains("MWArray")).ToList()[0];

    // Get all available types of MWArray
    List<Type> MWArrayTypes = mwArrayAssembly.GetTypes().ToList();                          

    // Create some MWArrays
    // MWNummericArray
    dynamic array1 = Activator.CreateInstance(MWArrayTypes[9], new object[] { new byte[640 * 480]});
    //MWNummericArray
    dynamic array2 = Activator.CreateInstance(MWArrayTypes[9], new object[] { 100 });
    //MWLogicalArray
    dynamic array3 = Activator.CreateInstance(MWArrayTypes[5], new object[] { true });

    // Parameters for Matlab function 
    object[] params= new object[] { array1, array2, array3};

    MethodInfo matlabFuncion = methods[5];      
    var result = matlabFuncion.Invoke(dynamicObject, params);
}

// The ResolveEventHandler ensures the proper loading of dependent assemblies
// I wrote a crawler that would search inside the Matlab runtime for dependent 
// assemblies. It is enough to just load "MWArray" from a static path... 
private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Assembly dependentAssembly = null;
    string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];
    string assemblypath = _crawler.getFullName(_runtimepath, assemblyName);
    if (assemblypath != string.Empty)
        dependentAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblypath);
    return dependentAssembly;
}
```